# Read XML file with XmlReader (PortableClassLibrary)

Tags: xml, linq-to-xml, streamreader, xmlreader, portable-class-library

I'm trying to read a xml file wiht XMLReader. In my WPF solution, it looked like this:

```
public XmlDocument XmlDoc;
XmlReaderSettings settings;
XElement Catalogue;

public void LoadXML(string XML_File)
{
  XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(XML_File, settings);
  XmlDoc.Load(reader);

  Catalogue = XElement.Load(new XmlNodeReader(XmlDoc));
}
```

Since I'm using Portable Class Library (Silverlight, WP8, .NET 4.5, Windows 8), there's no `XMLDocument` and no `XmlNodeReader`. I've tried to do it like this now:

```
public void LoadXML(string XML_File)
{
    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create();

    XDocument XmlDocx = XDocument.Load(reader);

    Catalogue = XElement.Load(reader);
}
```

but I don't know how I can put the string `XML_File` (which contains for example 'Users.xml') into the reader. XmlReader.Create() needs as a parameter a StreamReader or Textreader and when I declare a new StreamReader, the StreamReader needs as a parameter a Stream...? So yeah, I did it like that

```
public void LoadXML(string XML_File)
{
    //How to put the XML_File in the Stream?
    //I could say Stream sra = Stream.Null; - but I still need to put the XML_File string somehow into the reader
    Stream s = new Stream();
    StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(s);

    XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create(sr);

    XDocument XmlDocx = XDocument.Load(reader);

    Questions = XElement.Load(reader);
}
```

How can I put the XML_File ('Users.xml') into the reader so that I can load the reader with my `XmlDoc`?

Comment: The portable class library does not provide a unified file I/O, so you will not be able to access your XML file through this approach. Take a look at [PCLStorage](https://pclstorage.codeplex.com/) for a portable file I/O approach.

Answer (score 4):

You can't just pass a path to a file on Silverlight or Windows Store- they have different ways to access persisted storage.  You can use my [PCL Storage](https://pclstorage.codeplex.com/) library to provide a common way to do File I/O in Portable Class Libraries.

I'd also recommend reading my post on [How to make Portable Class Libraries work for you](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dsplaisted/archive/2012/08/27/how-to-make-portable-class-libraries-work-for-you.aspx) for some general advice on using PCLs.